# @PreUpdate on child that modifies parent property does not trigger revision of parent entity

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

I'm using Hibernate Envers to audit two entities (parent and child with a OneToOne relation). Both entities have @Audited and auditing is working.

When updating a property of the child, I would like to trigger a revision of the parent. Since this is not the case out of the box, I added the following method to the **child** entity:

```
@PreUpdate
public void preUpdate() {
    this.getParent().setTimeUpdated(Instant.now());
}
```

The listener works and I see the updated timestamp in the database and I also see a new revision for the child. However, I don't see a revision for the parent. Why?

I found some related topics on Hibernate ORM 6 ([ticket](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12151)), but I feel like this simple solution should work instead of having to implement custom audit listeners.

Comment: Is the `timeUpdated` property on the parent audited?  If it isn't, then the change won't actually trigger a revision for the parent entity.

Comment: Yes it is audited. If I manually set a new value to the timeUpdated property in my business logic, I get a revision for both parent & child.